# How to set Vue.js v-model value as hidden [ Laravel10 ]

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I study Vue.js v-model and I can get value.
so my next step. I would like to recive the value to Laravel10 controller.

I would like to get the value as hidden.
I wrote like this. but seems like I couldn't get the value.

Here is my souce code which after display v-model value.

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ n1 }}" name="n1" v-model="n1">
```

Could someone teach me correct way please?

Here is my current code.

**Number_vm.vue**

```
<input v-model.number="n1" /> {{ n1 }}
```

**index.blade.php**

```
<div id="number_vm">
  <number_vm01-component></number_vm01-component>
</div>


<input type="hidden" value="@{{ n1 }}" name="n1" v-model="n1">
```

> [UPDATE] My current code

```
<input :value="text" @input="onInput" placeholder="Type here" />
<input type="hidden" value="{{ text }}" name="text" />
```

Comment: Please check the Vue Tutorial [Step 5: Form Binding](https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-5) and [Examples : Form Binding](https://vuejs.org/examples/#form-bindings) on hot to use `v-model`  in forms

Comment: Dear @Tolbxela Thank you for answering me. I looked the page which you sent. and rewrite code. but I couldn't recive value. I update my current code. Could you take a look please?

Comment: Dear @Tolbxela Thank you for helping me.
I've been searching solution but seems like to pass data as hidden is pretty hard I think. I will try useing Axios. Thank you very much.